# spring mvc hibernate date picker date validater bootstrap

Tags: hibernate, date, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I am using bootstrap datepicker

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 cpl-md-4">
<input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="taskPDC"
                                                name="pdcDate" path="pdcDate" value="pdcDate">
    <form:errors path="pdcDate" cssClass="error" />

</div>
```

i need to vlidate this date using hibernate validator not null and future and some other corresponding date.when i am trying to validate on error date selected earlier going missing and typeconversion error exveption coming.i need to give custom error message.The date selected earlier must seected when error and i am getting type conversion error only when i add validtion annotation addes otherwise saving correctly in to db.

thanks